# Methods & Variables Calling Questions

Tags: java, methods, static

I've written this short code a while ago:

```
public class Check {
public static int gold, silver;
public int level=1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("You are now level " + level + "!");
    String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive number:");
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
    if (num2 < 0) {
        next();
    } else {
        main();
    }
}
public void next() {
    System.out.println("Thank you!");
}
```

}

I have 3 problems with this code:

1. If I make a public static Integer variable, I cannot set a number to it while declaring it. And I have to set a number while declaring. EDITED: My bad, it is possible to assign a number to it while declaring.

   If I make a public Integer variable, I can declare it and set a number to it, but for some reason I cannot use it in the public static void Main, which I have to, too.
2. Since next() is not a static void, I cannot call it from the main(String[] args) void.
   I don't want to make next() static, because then I'll be unable to use public Integers that are not static.
3. I cannot return (call) main() from main() itself. It's necessary for when invalid input is detected.

What can I do about these problems?

Comment: You should read this to get a basic understanding of java variables http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use static method, you have to create a class object in your main method and use it to call the next() method.

```
Check obj = new Check();
obj.next();
```

Comment: Thanks, works great.

Also, is there any reason to create static voids, or I better make new voids non-static?

Comment: `static` and `void` are two completely different things. `static` methods are usually best left avoided - they tend to show poor OO design.

Answer (score 2):

> If I make a public static Integer variable, I cannot set a number to it while declaring it.

Yes you can.

> If I make a public Integer variable, I can declare it and set a number to it, but for some reason I cannot use it in the public static void Main

That's because static methods cannot make use of non-static attributes.

> I cannot return (call) main() from main() itself. It's necessary for when invalid input is detected.

Yes you can, but you need to pass parameters.

Comment: Thank you, but writing main(); gives me the following error:

method main in class Check cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: @BarSharabani Yes, as Nicolai pointed out, you need to give an argument to the main method.

Answer (score 1):

1. You did mistake somewhere.
2. You have no access to non-static static members from static methods ( main is static ).
3. You forgot about parameters

try this variant:

```
public class Check {
    public static int gold, silver;
    public static int level = 1;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "You are now level " + level + "!" );
        String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter a positive number:" );
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt( num1 );
        if( num2 < 0 ) {
            next();
        }
        else {
            main(args);
        }
    }

    public static void next( ) {
        System.out.println( "Thank you!" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly.

But I have a question: If I only do public int (non-static) I cannot use it in static methods. Why is that?

Comment: You must to read java tutorials to understand this completely. In two words static members are class members, and non-static members are object members. Reading this article may help to understand http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html . The main page for tutorials is there: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html .

Answer (score 0):

Several comments.

1) *If I make a public static Integer variable, I cannot set a number to it while declaring it*

**Why?**

You should very easily be able to declare it thus:

```
public static int level = 1;
```

Then you code would work fine.

2) Avoid *static* - don't call your program logic from `main`, use `main` to bootstrap your application:

```
public int gold, silver;
public int level = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Check().read();
}

public void read() {
    System.out.println("You are now level " + level + "!");
    String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive number:");
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
    if (num2 < 0) {
        next();
    } else {
        read();
    }
}

public void next() {
    System.out.println("Thank you!");
}
```

So you make everything instance scoped and then create an *instance* of `Check` in `main`.

I would also note that you are using Swing GUI classes off of the EDT which breaks Swing's single threaded model, therefore this code is fundamentally flawed.